# Каталог паттернов проектирования

Tags: ооп, шаблоны-проектирования

Здравствуйте. Подскажите, пожалуйста, где можно найти наиболее полный каталог паттернов проектирования? Важно наличие UML диаграммы, краткого описания задач, решаемых паттерном.

Comment: http://habrahabr.ru/post/210288/ частично должно помочь

Comment: ещё в вики посмотрите по запросу "шаблоны проектирования".

Comment: А книга банды четырех? Вроде там неплохо все изложено, зато классика.

Comment: Коллеги, спасибо за помощь. Но я хочу найти каталог, который периодически будет обновляться. Погуглив, нашел вот такой сайт http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PatternIndex 
Вот пример описания паттерна http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?MessagingPattern
Т.е. есть описание, назначение, пример кода. Хотелось бы еще и UML диаграмму. Кто-нибудь находил ресурсы подобного рода?

UPD. Нашел еще вот такой ресурс - http://hillside.net/patterns/patterns-catalog
Содержит список сайтов с каталогами паттернов

Comment: Паттерны ради паттернов?

Comment: Маст хэв для прочтения Книга "Design Patterns via C#" - http://itvdn.com/ru/patterns

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- [Классика от Мартина Фаулера](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/), плюс [русскоязычная версия](http://design-pattern.ru)
- GoF
- [Список в Википедии](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_design_pattern#Classification_and_list)
- Описания, диаграммы, код: [.NET Design patterns](http://www.dofactory.com/net/design-patterns)
- http://www.oodesign.com
- Список с подробными описаниями: https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns
- Упомянутый вами http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PatternIndex
- Еще один каталог оттуда же:
  http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?SoftwareDesignPatternsIndex

Comment: Спасибо за подборку

Comment: @NicholasEssen не за что.